# Boilerpipe to extract non-english news articles

Tags: character-encoding, boilerpipe

I am trying to use [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) to extract news articles from non-english text. I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260010/using-boilerpipe-to-extract-non-english-articles) and its not working for me. I made following changes
1) Modified HTMLfetcher.java. Appended following lines before end of method fetch

```
byte[] utf8 = new String(data, cs.displayName()).getBytes("UTF-8"); //new one (convertion)
    cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); //set the charset to UFT-8
```

Or/And then
2) Changes code in class by using UTF-8 charset with Inuts

```
`URL url = new URL(urls);
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        is.setByteStream(url.openStream());


        text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(is);`
```

Still it did not work
Test URL: http://www.sandesh.com/article.aspx?newsid=2905443 
Text: મુંબઈ, 30 જાન્યુઆરી

સલમાન ખાને ગુજરાતમાં આવીને નરેન્દ્ર મોદીના વખાણ શુ કર્યા તેની મુસીબતોમાં ખૂબ વધારો થઈ ગયો છે. સલમાન ખાન ફિલ્મ 'જય હો'ના પ્રમોશન માટે ઉત્તરાયણમાં અમદાવાદ આવ્યા હોવાથી અને તે સમયે તેણે નરેન્દ્ર મોદીના વખાણ કર્યા હોવાથી કોંગ્રેસ દ્વારા મુસ્લિમોને તેની ફિલ્મ 'જય હો' ના જોવાની અરજી કરવામાં આવી હતી અને હવે મુસ્લિમ મૌલવીઓ દ્વારા તેના સામે ફતવો જાહેર કરી દેવામાં આવ્યો છે.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clearly been able to get ArticleExtractor to parse utf-8 text. The (likely) problem is that boilerplate's algorithms are specifically tailored to English and aren't working so well on a Gujarati (?) article. The algorithms use verbosity of phrases (eg: number of words per phrase) as well as some specific phrases (comments, have your say, etc) to determine the barriers of the article, as well as what pieces within the article are content or non content.

Have a look in the `boilerpipe/filters/english` directory of the library for more info on the algorithms. Unfortunately to get the same level of accuracy in non-English languages you would need to repeat their study on each language, or have a list of translated stop words and an idea about verbosity for each language you use.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But my question was with encoding where I get all ??????? instead of non-english text. Though boilerpipe   works best for english text but I also get good result for non-english text as well.

Comment: Frankly its my bad, the intention is to get extraction done with same non-english language instead of ?????(question marks or garbage characters) as output. Check my same question in a related thread[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260010/using-boilerpipe-to-extract-non-english-articles)

Answer (score 0):

First - The accepted answer is correct. Boilerpipe's algorithms are specifically tailored to English. However that does not mean it cannot return rough content in other languages. Please read complete accepted answer, below can be a crapshoot and you may not always get good content...

**Java-**

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;

public class BoilerpipeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            //some wrestling match in Russian from Russian newspaper
            URL url = new URL("http://www.azeri.ru/az/traditions/kuraj_pehlevanov/");

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            is.setByteStream(url.openStream());

            String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(is);
            System.out.println(text);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Next, if you are using Eclipse-**

Click on Run > Run Configurations > and select the Common Tab, then Encoding to Other(UTF-8), then click Run like so:

[image]